# Send email with Excel attachment using @nestjs/mailer

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nodemailer, exceljs

I'm trying to send email with excel attachment through @nestjs/mailer:

```
await this.mailService.send({ //service with @nestjs/mailer
      to: messageTo,
      subject: messageTitle,
      template: 'application-approved',
      context: {
        content: messageBody,
      },
      attachments: attachments.map(({ name, arrayBuffer }) => ({ // array with filenames and arrayBuffers
        filename: name, // filename like `name.xlsx`
        contents: arrayBuffer, // arrayBuffer contains filled excel file
        contentType: // tried to remove this property - no effect
          'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
      })),
    });
```

When a message arrives, all attachments are marked as broken. I tried to send both ArrayBuffer and Buffer - It had no effect.

In other hand HTTP route that creates the file and attach it to response succeeds.

**Any ideas to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used `@nestjs/mailer`, but since it uses `nodemailer` under the hood, I would try this:

```
await this.mailService.send({
  to: messageTo,
  subject: messageTitle,
  template: 'application-approved',
  context: {
    content: messageBody,
  },
  attachments: attachments.map(({ name, arrayBuffer }) => ({
    filename: name,
    contents: Buffer.from(arrayBuffer).toString('base64'),
    contentTransferEncoding: 'base64',
    contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  })),
});
```

If that doesn't work, maybe you should **check if the file content is correct in the first place**. You can save the file on the disk and open it, if that doesn't work then it's a data problem, not a transfer problem.

Also, check the type definitions for `nodemailer` attachments, to see what other options you have:

```
interface AttachmentLike {
  /** String, Buffer or a Stream contents for the attachmentent */
  content?: string | Buffer | Readable | undefined;
  /** path to a file or an URL (data uris are allowed as well) if you want to stream the file instead of including it (better for larger attachments) */
  path?: string | Url | undefined;
}

interface Attachment extends AttachmentLike {
  /** filename to be reported as the name of the attached file, use of unicode is allowed. If you do not want to use a filename, set this value as false, otherwise a filename is generated automatically */
  filename?: string | false | undefined;
  /** optional content id for using inline images in HTML message source. Using cid sets the default contentDisposition to 'inline' and moves the attachment into a multipart/related mime node, so use it only if you actually want to use this attachment as an embedded image */
  cid?: string | undefined;
  /** If set and content is string, then encodes the content to a Buffer using the specified encoding. Example values: base64, hex, binary etc. Useful if you want to use binary attachments in a JSON formatted e-mail object */
  encoding?: string | undefined;
  /** optional content type for the attachment, if not set will be derived from the filename property */
  contentType?: string | undefined;
  /** optional transfer encoding for the attachment, if not set it will be derived from the contentType property. Example values: quoted-printable, base64. If it is unset then base64 encoding is used for the attachment. If it is set to false then previous default applies (base64 for most, 7bit for text). */
  contentTransferEncoding?: '7bit' | 'base64' | 'quoted-printable' | false | undefined;
  /** optional content disposition type for the attachment, defaults to ‘attachment’ */
  contentDisposition?: 'attachment' | 'inline' | undefined;
  /** is an object of additional headers */
  headers?: Headers | undefined;
  /** an optional value that overrides entire node content in the mime message. If used then all other options set for this node are ignored. */
  raw?: string | Buffer | Readable | AttachmentLike | undefined;
}
```

Comment: I'm changed @nestjs/mailer to nodemailer, and it works great without encoding buffer to base64. I think, the problem in @nestjs/mailer

Answer (score 0):

In the last version of `@nestjs-modules/mailer` (1.8.1) the parameters names are a little differents.

It may be a different package than the one you used.

The method name is also different: `sendMail`

Here is a working example:

```js
this.mailService.sendMail({
      to: messageTo,
      subject: messageTitle,
      template: 'application-approved',
      context: {
        content: messageBody,
      },
      attachments: attachments.map(({ name, arrayBuffer }) => ({ // array with filenames and arrayBuffers
        filename: name, // filename like `name.xlsx`
        content: arrayBuffer.toString('base64'),
        encoding: 'base64',
        contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
      })),
    });
```

Based on the `ISendMailOptions` definition (which is the options of the `sendMail` method.

The content attribute is not `contents` but `content`. I also encoded the content in base64, so it have to be defined in the `encoding` parameter.

```js
export interface ISendMailOptions extends SendMailOptions {
    attachments?: {
        filename: string;
        content?: any;
        path?: string;
        contentType?: string;
        cid?: string;
        encoding?: string;
        contentDisposition?: 'attachment' | 'inline' | undefined;
        href?: string;
    }[];
}
```